# Let $B\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $T:M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(A)=BA$. Find the rank of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $T:M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(A)=BA$. Find the rank of $T$

$\text{Im}(T)=\left\{ w\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}):T(v)=w, \forall v\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\right\} $

$\dim(\text{Im}(T))= \text{rank} (T)$

Now, Let

$B=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1} & b_{2}\\
b_{3} & b_{4}
\end{pmatrix}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1} & a_{2}\\
a_{3} & a_{4}
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, $BA=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1}a_{1}+b_{2}a_{3} & b_{1}a_{2}+b_{2}a_{4}\\
b_{3}a_{1}+b_{4}a_{3} & b_{3}a_{2}+b_{4}a_{4}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1} & \alpha_{2}\\
\alpha_{3} & \alpha_{4}
\end{pmatrix}$ with $\alpha_{i}\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $1\leq i\leq4$

$\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
b_{1}a_{1}+b_{2}a_{3}=\alpha_{1}\\
b_{1}a_{2}+b_{2}a_{4}=\alpha_{2}\\
b_{3}a_{1}+b_{4}a_{3}=\alpha_{3}\\
b_{3}a_{2}+b_{4}a_{4}=\alpha_{4}
\end{cases}$

In this step i'm stuck, what am I supposed to clear to get the rank of $T$?

Comment: The rank of $T$ does rather depend on what $B$ is. To warm up, think of the cases $B=O$ and $B=I$ first.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is this is to find the matrix T and then find the rankT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we find the matrix $\ T$ in respect to standard basis of $\ M_{2x2} $

Let $\ B=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0})=\pmatrix{a&0\\c&0}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0})=\pmatrix{0&a\\0&c}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0})=\pmatrix{b&d\\0&0}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1})=\pmatrix{0&b\\0&d}$

Then to the respect to the standard basis we form a matrix $\ T$

$\ T=\pmatrix{a&0&b&0\\0&a&b&d\\c&0&0&0\\0&c&0&d}$ then in the respect to $\ a,b,c,d$ we find the $\ rankT$

For $\ a,b,c,d\neq0\ rankT=4$

Cases where they are $\ 0$ I leave up to you to calculate the rank of T

Answer (score 1):

The rank of $T$ is $2$ times the rank of $B$.

Of course, this holds if $B = 0$ or $B$ is invertible.  In the case that $B$ has rank $1$ with a non-zero first column, note that the matrices
$$
B \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad B \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
form a basis of the image.