# some confusion that How this matrix come?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some  confusion in my mind  regarding this question :[Let $B\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $T:M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(A)=BA$. Find the rank of $T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257714/let-b-in-m-2-mathbbr-and-let-tm-2-mathbbr-rightarrow-m-2-math)

My  confusion is about  matrix  transformation  How  this matrix  come ?
as shown below[image]

Comment: I think by pretending a $2\times 2$ matrix as a $4\times 1$ column vector, like

$$\pmatrix{w&x\\y&z} \to \pmatrix{w\\x\\y\\z}$$

Though from $T(\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0})$ onwards some $b$ and $d$ are in wrong places...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are taking the basic matrix units $E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}$ as the basis of $M_2(\mathbb R)$. If we name this four elements in the basis as $F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4$, we have by definition of what the matrix of an operator with respect to a basis, 
$$
aF_1+cF_3=T(F_1)=T_{11}F_1+T_{21}F_2+T_{31}F_3+T_{41}F_4. 
$$
Comparing the two sides we get that the first column of $T$ is $a,0,c,0$. Similarly, 
$$
bF_1+dF_2=T(F_3)=T_{13}F_1+T_{23}F_2+T_{33}F_3+T_{43}F_4,
$$
from where we get that the third column of $T$ is $b,d,0,0$. And similarly for the other two columns.

Comment: Thank u @martin sir